# Работа с полями аннотации

Tags: java, аннотации

Добрый день господа.
У меня по неопытности появился вот какой вопрос.
Есть код моей аннотации, которая применяется к методу в рантайме:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface CanRun{
    int count();
}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне сделать так чтобы аннотация вызывала метод столько раз, сколько будет указано в значении count?

Comment: У вас наверняка есть обработчик этой аннотации? Там и надо это делать.

Comment: Да обработчик есть. Там просто 4 метода. Перед двумя стоят аннотации и вызывают их в рантайме. Как это сделать я понимаю, а как использовать поле каунт для кол-ва вызовов не понимаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Забираем аннотацию у метода и в цикле вызываем метод нужное количество раз. В самом простом примере должно быть примерно так:

```
Method method = myInstance.getClass().getMethod("methodName", methodParams);
CanRun annotation = method.getAnnotation(CanRun.class);
if (annotation != null) {
    int count = annotation.count();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        method.invoke(myInstance, parameters);
    }
}
```

где

`myInstance` - объект, у которого будут искаться методы

`methodParams` - классы параметров

`parameters` - список параметров, с которыми запустить метод

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а подскажите еще пожалуйста. Если мы указваем класс параметров, то метод получается должен принимать их?

Comment: если у вас метод выглядит так myMethod(java.uti.Date date, String s) то methodParams должны быть java.util.Date.class, String.class

Answer (score 2):

Очень упрощенный вариант, его можно взять за основу для вашего случая.

```
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

    for (Method method : Solution.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Annotation annotation : method.getDeclaredAnnotations())
            if (annotation.annotationType() == Repeat.class) {
                count = method.getAnnotation(Repeat.class).count();
                break;
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
            method.invoke(null);
    }
  }

  @Repeat(count = 10)
  public static void method() {
     System.out.println("hello world");
  }

  @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface Repeat {
      int count() default 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: В данном примере Annotation annotation это какая аннотация?

Comment: нет, это такой класс